# Grails JSON converter and JSONObject code breaks when moved to src/groovy

Tags: json, grails

I am trying to move some code from a grails service file into src/groovy for better reuse.

```
import grails.converters.JSON
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONObject

class JsonUtils {

    // seems like a clunky way to accomplish converting a domainObject
    // to its json api like object, but couldn't find anything better.
    def jsonify(obj, ArrayList removeableKeys = []) {
        def theJson = obj as JSON
        def reParsedJson = JSON.parse(theJson.toString())
        removeableKeys.each { reParsedJson.remove(it) }
        return reParsedJson
    }

    // essentially just turns nested JSONObject.Null things into java null things
    // which don't get choked on down the road so much.
    def cleanJson(json) {
        if (json instanceof List) {
            json = json.collect(cleanJsonList)
        } else if (json instanceof Map) {
            json = json.collectEntries(cleanJsonMap)
        }
        return json
    }

    private def cleanJsonList = {
        if (it instanceof List) {
            it.collect(cleanJsonList)
        } else if (it instanceof Map) {
            it.collectEntries(cleanJsonMap)
        } else {
            (it.class == JSONObject.Null) ? null : it
        }
    }

    private def cleanJsonMap = { key, value ->
        if (value instanceof List) {
            [key, value.collect(cleanJsonList)]
        } else if (value instanceof Map) {
            [key, value.collectEntries(cleanJsonMap)]
        } else {
            [key, (value.class == JSONObject.Null) ? null : value]
        }
    }

}
```

but when I try to call `jsonify` or `cleanJson` from services I get MissingMethodExceptions

example call from grails service file:

```
def animal = Animal.read(params.animal_id)
if (animal) json.animal = JsonUtils.jsonify(animal, ['tests','vaccinations','label'])
```

error:

```
No signature of method: static org.JsonUtils.jsonify() is applicable for argument types: (org.Animal, java.util.ArrayList) values: [ ...]]\ Possible solutions: jsonify(java.lang.Object, java.util.ArrayList), jsonify(java.lang.Object), notify()
```

Also tried making the jsonify take an animal `jsonify(Animal obj, ...)` then it just said `Possible solutions: jsonify(org.Animal, ...`

The cleanJson method was meant to deal with JSONObject.Null things which have caused problems for us before.

example call:

```
def safeJson = JsonUtils.cleanJson(json) // json is request.JSON from the controller
```

error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static org.JsonUtils.cleanJson() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONObject) values: [[...]]
Possible solutions: cleanJson(org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONObject)
```

All this code worked as it is when it was in service file. I am running grails 2.3.11 BTW

Comment: What's the name of package with `JsonUtils` class? And how you import it in services where you use methods from `JsonUtils`?

Comment: `import org.JsonUtils` in the services package is org

Comment: as the answers pointed out it was a simple issue. Turns out I have just been doing to much Javascript these days and forgot all about static stuff in JVM land... Threw a `static` on each of the methods/closures in the JsonUtils class and all was well.

Comment: Bonus points if anyone knows a better way to accomplish what I was going for in `jsonify` ;)

Comment: You want to convert domain class to JSON but omit some properties, right? If yes, custom marshaller should do the job -> http://compiledammit.com/2012/08/16/custom-json-marshalling-in-grails-done-right/

Comment: not exactly, already using a custom mashaller, but I want a simple java object that corresponds with the output of the marshaller, whereas when I use `as JSON` I get a JSONObject that doesn't embed well into other objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've declared `jsonify()` and `cleanJson()` as instance methods and try to use them as static. Declare them as static and it should work:

```
class JsonUtils {

    def static jsonify(obj, ArrayList removeableKeys = []) {
       (...)
    }

    def static cleanJson(json) {
        (...)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `jsonify()` and `cleanJson()` as `static` in order to call them statically.